# How to use PreferenceFragment settings in other fragments?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, androidx

I have a PreferenceFragment that contains 1 setting. It is defined (and called) with the following code :

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings, rootKey);
            loadSettings()

}

private fun loadSettings() {
    val sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.context)

    val safemode = sp.getBoolean("safemode", false)
}
```

}

The fragment pops up normally and everything is good, but I do not have good understanding of SharedPreferences (I tried reading tutorials but I couldn't get it).

How do I store and use the settings in other fragments?

Comment: The settings modified in this Fragment are automatically stored. Your `loadSettings` function shows the correct way to retrieve the value of a setting, although it is pointless here because you don't do anything with that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `SharedPreferences` is for store small data (preferred strings) in it.
Technically it is XML file that save key value type of data.
You can have your `SharedPreferences` as static and use it every where you want.
To obtain shared preferences, use the following method In your Application/Activity/Fragment:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
      "com.example.app.test", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To read preferences:

```
String dummyKey = "dummyKey";

String l = prefs.getString(dummyKey, "default value");
```

To edit and save preferences

```
String dt = getSomeString();
prefs.edit().putString(dummyKey, dt).apply();
```

`commit()` return true if value saved successfully otherwise false. It save values to SharedPreferences synchronously.

`apply()` was added in 2.3 and doesn't return any value either on success or failure. It saves values to SharedPreferences immediately but starts an asynchronous commit.